SwiftData 30 seconds delay on autosave

So, since I updated to Xcode 16.1 and iOS 18, my SwiftData project who relies on autosave doesn't work as expected.
Indeed, it works but only after a delay, around 30 seconds.
So if I add something to the database, I must wait around this delay to quit and relaunch the app, to see the changes persist.
I researched but didn't find any fix, besides using context.save() but since the method can throw errors, I cannot find exactly what errors and so, how to react to them.
If you have a solution, or just an idea, please let me know :)
Thanks a lot guys.

I see the same delay but only until I minimise the app or kill it from the device (simulator) so I see no data loss when handling it normally, only when killing the app from Xcode. I don't understand the part about not being able to call save() on the ModelContext.

@JoakimDanielson Oh, I can call save() from the modelContext without a problem ! The thing is, the save() method throws errors and I can't find anywhere what errors exactly. So I don't know how to treat them, what to say to the user and what's the best practice to follow. For the moment, I display an error message saying the user should reboot the app, but if I knew the errors thrown by save(), I could be more precise :(

Surround by do/catch and have print(error) in the catch to start with to determine what error you get? Then you can add better error handling later on but that is another issue. That said if your call to save() throws an error then the automatic save will also generate an error or there is something wrong with how you save. But again this is another issue.

I could do that yes, but It's really weird to me that we don't have informations on the possible errors. Thanks btw

I’m voting to close this question because even if there is a delay the save will always be performed if not before so on quit or when the app goes into the background.

Actually I am having the same issues since iOS18 and I worked around it to call save() on all my inserting or deleting operations. I know quite some people complaining about that. It seems there is indeed a change from iOS17 to iOS 18. For me, also on closing the app (in Simulator) changes are not saved.

@ArminScheithauer yea, I guess we should put save() everywhere for the moment, and it seems it's better that way, according to some ios devs I've talked to ;)
